# Repeated class container to take the height of last-child position and height

Tags: jquery, position, containers, css-position, css-selectors

I have a repeated div container class="content" which contains absolute positioned divs.

```
.content{
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
}

 .article0{
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
}

 .article1{
   width: 230px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 80px;
}

 .article2{
   width: 230px;
   position: absolute;
}

 .article3{
   width: 230px;
   position: absolute;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   top: 500px;
}
```

As is said the container class="content" is repeating in the same page many times:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="article1"></div>
<div class="article2"></div>
<div class="article3"></div>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to do is give the container the height and top position of the last child in each container with class .content. I have tried the below code but without any result, the containers keep getting only the same height value, i guess only from the last child of the last or first container? Can't figure out!

```
$(function(){
var $box = $('.content');
var lastChildPos = $(':last-child', $box).position().top;
var lastChildHeight = $(':last-child', $box).height();

$box.height(lastChildPos + lastChildHeight);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`If there is multiple instances you will need something like this:

```
$('.content').each(function(){

    var lastChildPos = $(':last-child', $(this)).position().top;
    var lastChildHeight = $(':last-child', $(this)).height();

    $(this).height(lastChildPos + lastChildHeight);

});
```

That way it applies it to each instance of box, and `$(this)` gets the variables in relation to each container.

Note: :last-child will select the last child of a type within a parent container. Maybe you want to try:

```
var lastChildPos = $(this).find('div:last-child').position().top;
```

Comment: Shoulda posted for a +1 anyways :P

Comment: Thans Rick, I've tried with each before without results. Tried your code and now it gets the height of the first child(!) ignoring the top position! Can't find what's wrong!

Comment: By inspecting the result thoroughly i see that for the first 3 containers with class '.content', it gets the height of the first child ignoring it's top positioning, while for the last container which has only one child, the height is the childs height + top position. Can't figure it out! Any ideas?

Comment: That was like PERFECT!. Tested and worked, 'div' is necessary for the position too. MANY THANKS!